# Is there anyway for me to grab users' personal interest from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, html-parsing, collaborative-filtering

I made a recommendation system using collaborative filtering technique and I want to check if my system works well or not.

To do that, I want to collect people's personal interest (such as their favorite movie, music or pages something like that). I'm not interested in their real name or some other privacy-sensitive information.

I thought I can easily achieve them using Facebook API, Permission from each user required and this seems not feasible.

So, Another solution that I'm considering is to parse it from HTML source of facebook. But I don't know whether I'm thinking in the right way.

Is there anyone who can give me a hint for this process?? T_T

Answer (score 2):

You will be breaking every TOS Facebook has if you do that.

You must gain permission from each user.

I would go about in thinking how could you get each user to give you that permission. Maybe develop a contest, get it out with a few contests, you grab heaps of user info for your test and someone wins a prize :)

Just one possible way.

Or how many friends on Facebook do you have that will let you do this?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Building another application for the test of the system.... does not sounds that simple..
And I need around 1,000 people and I don't have that many friends...
But still the first solution sounds interesting... thanks for your help... I'm really sorry for the fact that it's not possible to achieve the information automatically....

Comment: Yes it is unfortunate, the only other things I could recommend is just using a bunch of made up test data, or getting the permission from someone who has an app with over a 1,000 users. Though that might be a bit controversial since the users never agreed to it.

Comment: Thanks for your support Adams. :)
I already tested with dataset from Movielens but, I wanted to check if my system works on real interests (Not limited to movies) or not.
Your second solution sounds good. I think I should look for someone with that data.
Thanks for your help again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can request the `user_likes` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from any of your app's users and then retrieve the likes and interests from the `/<USER>/likes` endpoint in the Graph API

Comment: Yes I know that... I was wondering if I can retrieve them without having permission.... But, still thanks for your help :)